# A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'SimpleMvcServices.Startup' type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration

I have to create Integration tests for a project of .NET framework 4.5.2, I need to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` which calls `Startup` in the initialization:

```
TestServer server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
```

but I always get this exception since the startup.cs file contains only configuration method:

> A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not
>   be found in the 'SimpleMvcServices.Startup' type

Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SimpleMvcServices.Startup))]

namespace SimpleMvcServices
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. Your method name is wrong (not one of the two options allowed).

Comment: Indeed: "Configuration" != "ConfigureProduction" OR "Configure". Actually I am a bit confused that this testing API does not provide any interface to inherit from. That should usually deal with any such issues.

Comment: I renamed the method to one of the mentioned in the exception but didn't work


Could not resolve a service of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' for the parameter 'app' of method 'Configure' on type 'SimpleMvcServices.Startup'

Comment: That is a different question @Tas. You should write up a new question for that.

Answer (score -1):

Add a method

```
Public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder, IWebHostingEnvironment){
// your logic goes here
}
```

Its a mandatory for ASP netcore apps.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.0

read about Startup class

Comment: This is not a .Net Core application. The hosting app is, but the application being loaded is .Net 4.5.2 which does not support `IApplicationBuilder` nor `IWebHostingEnvironment`. Is there a way to use a .NET (formerly called .Net Core) application to host a .Net Framework application?